# Run a stateful RPC server in python

Tags: python-2.7, rpc, stateful

I need to run an rpc server in python 2.7.9 that take one object that should run forever and update its state consistently.  Here below the pseudo-code:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def update_count(self):
        self.count += 1
```

and a an RPC server that will listen on a port

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def start_state_service(self):
        while True:
            self.state.update_count()
            time.sleep(2)

    def start_rpc_server(self):
        start_to_listen(localhost, 9000)

    def get_count(self):
        return self.state.count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    state = State()
    srv = Server(state)
    srv.start_state_service()
    srv.start_rpc_server()
```

And the Client would look like that:

```
class Client(object):
    def get_count(self):
        c = connect_to_server(localhost, 9000) 
        c.get_count()
```

Could you please tell me how you would implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.  My service will be an object inherit from multiprocessing so that it can be launch on the background.  Then I create a SimpleXMLRPCServer that will listen on request.  I have found no way to provide the state of the object (i.e. count) other than putting an update of the object in the pickle file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8


"""
Create an XML-RPC Server that register several serices that run
in paralel in the background but can be invoked to know their state
"""


import multiprocessing
import time
import pickle
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer


class Service(multiprocessing.Process):
    """A service the increment a variable. """

    def __init__(self):
        """TODO: to be defined1. """
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0

    def update_count(self):
        """ Update the counter """
        self.count += 1
        database = open('datafile.pkl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.count, database)
        database.close()

    def run(self):
        """ Overloaded function provided by multiprocessing.Process.
            Called upon start() signal """
        end_time = time.time() + 120
        while time.time() < end_time:
            self.update_count()
            print self.count
            time.sleep(2)


def main():
    """ Main function """
    srv = Service()
    srv.start()

    def get_count():
        """Get state for the object"""
        database = open('datafile.pkl', 'rb')
        data = pickle.load(database)
        return data

    swift_srv = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 9000), logRequests=True,
                                   allow_none=True)
    swift_srv.register_function(get_count)

    try:
        print 'Use Control-C to exit'
        swift_srv.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Exiting'

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

And then the Client is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8


import xmlrpclib

proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:9000', allow_none=True)
print proxy.get_count()
```